# Custom NewRelic .NET application name

Tags: .net, configuration, newrelic

So I have a background application, call it App.exe, and in my newrelic.config file underneath the configuration node I have:

```
<instrumentation log="true">
  <applications>
    <application name="App.exe" />
  </applications>
</instrumentation>
```

which reports fine.

Problem is the application executable name is App.exe on our QA servers as well as production, but they will all go into the same new relic "application" as just App. Is there a way to change that? I can't change it in the above "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a **newrelic.config** file at the same location as the .exe file and it will get picked up instead of the main one in the agent install location. Once this is done you can alter the application name in the following location (near the top of the file):

```
<application>
   <name>My Application</name>
</application>
```

You will probably need to restart the application in order for this to get picked up.